# How to use the redux store and let the user access the admin panel - React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this flow in my application. The user registers/logs in and a JWT is saved in the browser's storage. Each time the user refreshes the page if the JWT is present and the store doesn't have the user already there, it makes a request to the api and returns a json containing the user.

index.js

```
if (localStorage.websiteJWT) {
    setAuthorizationHeader(localStorage.websiteJWT);
    if(!store.getState().user.email)
        store.dispatch(fetchCurrentUser());
}
```

and now I have the user present in the store. The user object looks like this:

```
{user: {username: "Bob", admin: true}}
```

Now I have the following routes for users:

AdminRoute:

--

and a normal Route which will be used for everybody else.

This is how an admin route looks like:

`<AdminRoute exact location={location} path='/admin/locations' component={LocationsPage}/>`

Now I have the following situations:

1)The admin user is already on the site, the store already has the required state `state.user.admin` and he goes to the `localhost:3000/admin/locations` page without any problems.

2)The admin user goes straight from the browser to that page at which point the store doesn't have the user info present and starts to fetch it, but by the time it comes back the redirect has already happened. In this situation, the admin user can never access the admin panel.

I know this because I can see in the console the store printing a few times 
`Is user admin? undefined` and a few times `Is user admin? true`.
How can I solve situation 2?

The only solution that I thought of was to have a user object stored in the localStorage like the token. It is not ideal as it is easy to bypass. Even if it wouldn't give access to real data as the token wouldn't be valid, I don't like this option.

Edit: I tried to implement the solution suggested in the comments. I do have a `loaded: false` initial redux state.

```
export default function user(state = { loaded: false }, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOGGED_IN:
            return {...action.user, loaded: true};
        case USER_FETCHED:
            return {...state, ...action.user, loaded: true};
        case USER_LOGGED_OUT:
            return {};
        case USER_CONFIRMED:
            return {...state, confirmed: true};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and I changed my AdminRoute accordingly:

```
const AdminRoute = ({ loaded, isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    console.log(`Is user admin? ${isAuthenticated}`);
    console.log(`Loaded? ${loaded}`);
    return (

        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                <div>
                     loaded && isAuthenticated &&
                    <div>
                            <AdminNavigation />
                            <Component {...props} />
                    </div>

                      loaded && !isAuthenticated && <Redirect to="/" />
                </div>
            }
        />
    )
};

AdminRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
    loaded: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
        loaded: state.user.loaded,
        isAuthenticated: state.user.admin
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminRoute);
```

but this line `loaded && !isAuthenticated && <Redirect to="/" />` still triggers before the one above and I still get redirected.

I also get

```
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

I assume that this happens because it's trying to render the `LocationsPage` component after the `Redirect`.

Comment: the clear answer is: don't redirect until you know for sure. keep a piece of state for "loadingUserInfo", either in redux or inside your adminRoute as a third option to redirecting or passing through

Comment: @azium I tried to implement what you suggested, but I still get a problem. Could you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: I think it's because you're doing `!isAuthenticated` and it's `null` or `undefined` which is also falsey. either a) explicitly check for `false` and make sure its `null` or `undefined` in your initial state, or b) make sure you don't set the loading state before you set isAuthenticated state. ie only dispatch once. can you post your dispatch calls?

Comment: You have to wrap the javascript expression in `{}` inside jsx.  `{loaded && !isAuthenticated && (<Redirect to="/" />)}` or it will be interpreted as just text.

Comment: @HåkenLid omg thank you. No idea how I missed that. It is working now.